# Make html a tag href wait for async function in onclick to return?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have this link with an onclick that's supposed to execute before the href

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="?mode=full" onclick="req('name=vmode&value=full','POST','/cookie')">Promeni rezim prikaza</a>
```

And the relevant parts of the called js function looks like this:

```
function req(data='',method='GET',url='',lang='',el='null'){
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Http.open(method,url);
```

...

```
const e = document.getElementById(el);
    if (e && e.value != '' || !e)
        Http.send(msg);
```

or return false whatever

Now this only works when I set

```
Http.open(method,url,false);
```

But I get warned from my browser's console about how doing this on the main thread is deprecated and it straight up doesn't allow half of my script to work even if I'm not calling that part(weird)

How does one properly do this? i.e make it await the async function

Comment: Why would async questions be "cringe"?

Comment: Maybe because people keep asking them and none understands async, "agh that async", but even if so, you're right, there's no dumb questions as long as I couldn't easily find what I needed with a search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass then `event` of the click to your function: `onclick="req(event, 'name=vm....`

Then your function can [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) it, so that the default action of the click is not executed.

Now wait for your network request to return (probably want to use [`fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch), that's much simpler than the old `XMLHttpRequest`).

Once the promise resolved, trigger the redirect to the target URL:

```
<body>
    <a href="?mode=full" onclick="req(event, 'name=vmode&value=full','POST','/cookie')">Promeni rezim prikaza</a>
</body>
<script>
function req(event, data='',method='GET',url='/index.html?test') {
    console.debug(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(url, {method: "POST"}).then(() => {
        location.href = event.target.href;
    });
}
</script>
```

But consider that your users may have to wait for the request in the background and don't understand what is going on.

If you only want to send some statistics data, you may want to consider using the new [`sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) API. It sends data (`POST` only) **async** in the background, so that the link target can be loaded for the user, while the browser works on the `sendBeacon()` requests in the background.

Comment: method: "POST" -> method: method

Didn't test yet but
Excellent answer, very informative and helps me achieve what I want in better ways, not only solve my problem.
sendBeacon() sounds like exactly what I'd need since I'm putting in a cookie to remember connecting to that version of my page and then connecting to it, so the request is not vital to the page itself
But I'm also using the same function in other places to stop the connection and print out that some required fields are missing. I will add the background request as an option, I'm wary of performance, I minify everything :)