# Anchor tag click - wait for response or get response async

Tags: javascript

I am using an anchor tag in javascript for downloading a large file (could be 50-100 GB).

```
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.display = 'none'
  a.href = requestUrl
  a.download = 'logs.zip'
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  document.body.removeChild(a)
```

Download start can take 5-15 minutes as backend collects the data and then responds with a zip file.

But there could be times when an error is encountered and download doesn't start at all. **Is there a way to get status of the API called via anchor tag.**

Note: I have tried other approaches as well but none of those work.

1. ajax get call - this keeps data in RAM/memory and fails once that limit is hit.
2. fetch - tried using streamsaver lib, but that didn't work either. Couldn't write stream to disk.
3. File system access APIs. - this works on chrome, but firefox doesn't support this. So, can't use it.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603149/make-html-a-tag-href-wait-for-async-function-in-onclick-to-return